# Get Length, Breadth and Width using Intel Real Sense Camera

Tags: 3d, artificial-intelligence

I want to find 3d dimensions of an object in an image. With mobile phone camera and using the code [here](https://pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/28/measuring-size-of-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/) I can compute dimensions of an object within an image using a reference object.

Following are the challenges

- I simply can't get 3d dimensions.
- Objects within objects detected and are not required.

If someone has experience using Intel Real sense depth camera can I get 3d dimensions using that camera without using any reference objects? Also which variant of camera is most suitable for this purpose also do I need multiple cameras to achieve this?

Comment: With a depth camera it should be fairly easy to estimate the size of an object since you know how far away from the camera each pixel is.  However, this doesn't really sound like a photography question, so you will probably have better chance for getting a useful answer on other sites.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be asked on an engineering/programming site.